# How to handle sub-domain in one project source?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, subdomain, nuxt3

I'm developing a project with Nuxt.js 3, with folder structure like this:

```
|─assets
|─components
|─pages
|   ├───admin
|   ├─────index.vue
|   ├───user
|   ├─────index.vue
|   └───other-folder.vue
|─plugins
|─stores
|─utils
```

in Nuxt.js 3, how to serve folder **admin** and **user** with different domain like this:

**example.com** for **user** folder

**admin.example.com** for **admin** folder

but, each domain/admin/user still can access assets, components, plugins, stores, and utils.